# Error in this line " String forecastStr = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);" in the sunshine project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem in this line "String forecastStr = mForecastAdapter.getItem (position);" . the line is fully underlined in red. when I put the mouse pointer on this line it shows that there is "incompatible type, required: java.lang.String found: java.lang.Object" I will put the image of my class to help you understand my problem, and thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast it:

```
String forecastStr = (String)mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getItem(position)` returns a generic `Object`. Cast it to a `String`.

`String forecastStr = (String) mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the adapter declaration, by doing this you don't need to explicitly cast to String

**From**

```
private ArrayAdapter mForecastAdapter;
```

**To**

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
```